# How to sort an array from the highest number to the lowest with a structure in C language

Tags: c

I have a task to create a structure with a car brand, model and price and make 3x of those and then I need to print the car info, but the order should be from the highest price to the lowest. I'm a begginer and I don't understand how to do it with a ,,for'' loop.[This is what I wrote so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLi6P.png)

Comment: copy the code here instead of images

Comment: And ask a specific question. That is, what problem do you have with the code as it is?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseudo-code for the selection sort :

```
L => your tab/list
START:
   i <- 1
   n <- #L (len of L)
   WHILE i < n DO
      i_minimum = Min_Index(L, i, n)
      Swap(L, i, i_minimum)
      i <- i + 1
   ENDWHILE 
 END
```

Some explications:

you have to create a function Min_Index(L, i, n) that's return the index of the min value in your tab and you have to create the swap function (useless because in C, you can just create a new tab for your sorting tab)

For your question, you need to sort your tab of structure, with the price value
So adapt the sort it would work :)

EDIT: I forgot that you need to sort in descending price. So instead of the Min_Index function, you need to create the opposite: Max_Index which return the index of the maximum value (maximum price)

Answer (score 0):

There are many techniques to sort an array. As you are a beginner i will show you linear sorting technique.First you need to create a "temp" variable for swapping contents which is of struct car type.Following is the code to insert in the for loop.Also there are some syntax errors in your code.Best of luck.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 1; j < 3; j++)
    {
      if (car[i].price > car[j].price)
      {
        temp = car[i];
        car[i] = car[j];
        car[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I create a "temp" variable and what is it? I'm sorry I'm new at this. Thank you in advance sir :)

Answer (score -1):

Every struct fields can be used like a classic variable.

Then you could do

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (cars[2].price == x) 
        // TODO
}
```

Comment: Don't see how this answers the question. It doesn't do any sorting.

Comment: There are no specific questions, therefore I assumed that he do not know how to use a struct. Anyway, there is a ton of sorting algorithm everywhere ..

Comment: If you don't know what the question is then ask for clarification in a comment.

Comment: @kaylum I am very sorry big master of StackOverflow, I won't do it anymore.